# Can i use my oauth 2.0 client id created in my laravel website for flutter app in simultaneously?

Tags: laravel, flutter, authentication, google-signin

I have an online store that I built by [Bagisto](https://bagisto.com), which depends on the Laravel platform and I created my oauth 2.0 client id in https://console.cloud.google.com/ for google sign in And it works fine.
Now I made a mobile application for this store using Flutter and I need to add a sign in with a Google account and I found this plugin [google_sign_in: ^5.3.1](https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in)
The question is  : Can i use my oauth 2.0 client id  created in my laravel website for flutter app in simultaneously? one client id for laravel and flutter .
please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every application has its own client id. As [google_sign_in](https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in) instructions says

> To access Google Sign-In, you'll need to make sure to register your
> application.